# Compare an element from one array with an element from another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays of numbers that have the same size. How can I tell if there is any element in the second array that is greater than the first array at a given index? With this example:

```
a = [2, 8, 10]
b = [3, 7, 5]
```

`3` is greater than `2` at position `0`. But in the following:

```
a = [1, 10]
b = [0, 8]
```

there is no such element. At index `0`, `0` is not greater than `1`, and at index `1`, `8` is not greater than `10`.

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: It can just be true or false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
a.each_with_index.any? { |item, index| b[index] > item }
```

Comment: Which reads better, what you have or `a.each_index.any? { |index| b[index] > a[index] }`?

Comment: I prefer your :D

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yours is also faster.

Answer (score 5):

No need for indices. Just pair them and check each pair.

```
b.zip(a).any? { |x, y| x > y }
=> true or false
```

And a tricky one: Check whether at every position, `a` is the maximum:

```
a.zip(b).map(&:max) != a
=> true or false
```

And a very efficient one (both time and space):

```
b.zip(a) { |x, y| break true if x > y }
=> true or nil
```

(If you need `true`/`false` (often you don't, for example in `if`-conditions), you could prepend `!!` or append `|| false`)

Comment: I could say  "no need for a new array" :D

Comment: @Ursus Well, then I could say "no need to assume that a new array is bad" or I could just plug a `.lazy` in there :-)

Comment: This is the cleanest answer here so far. `b.lazy.zip(a).any? { |x, y| x > y }` would be likely a bit better, yes.

Comment: @mudasobwa Well it really depends on the usage. For small cases like the OP's examples, adding `.lazy` just unnecessarily clutters the code and makes it slower. Anyway... I just added another solution that's very efficient in both time and space.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a number in `b` greater than the number in `a` at the given index, this will return the number in `b`. If no numbers in `b` are greater, `nil` will be returned.

```
b.detect.with_index { |n, index| n > a[index] }
```

For example, if you have the following arrays.

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8]
```

You'll get a return value of `6`.